# sed - address space between "{" and "},"

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, sed

I specify the address space between "{" and "}," in sed, so I expect only the first "Acer" to be replaced to "TTTT". Second one is not expected. How can I fix this problem ?
I did test on Ubuntu 15.10 and sed version is sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2.

Thanks in advance.

```
$ echo "
[
    {
        \"manufacturer\": \"Acer\",
        \"regularPrice\": 165.99,
    },
    [
        \"manufacturer\": \"Acer\",
        \"regularPrice\": 165.99,
    ],
    {
        \"manufacturer\": \"Acer\",
        \"regularPrice\": 165.99,
    }
]
" | sed "/{/,/},/ {s/\"Acer\"/\"TTTT\"/}"
```

Its results are as follows:

```
[
  {
    "manufacturer": "TTTT",
    "regularPrice": 165.99,
  },
  [
    "manufacturer": "Acer",
    "regularPrice": 165.99,
  ],
  {
    "manufacturer": "TTTT",
    "regularPrice": 165.99,
  }
]
```

Comment: The second pattern in the address means "stop when this is found". It does not mean "don't proceed if this is not found".

Answer (score 1):

This will work only for `GNU sed`

```
sed "/{/,/},/ {0,/\"Acer\"/ s/\"Acer\"/\"TTTT\"/}"
```

or to be more precise the following is also working

```
sed "/{/,/},/ {0,/\"Acer\"/s//\"TTTT\"/}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '
[
    {
        "manufacturer": "Acer",
        "regularPrice": 165.99,
    },
    [
        "manufacturer": "Acer",
        "regularPrice": 165.99,
    ],
    {
        "manufacturer": "Acer",
        "regularPrice": 165.99,
    }
]
' | perl -0777 -pe 's/({[^}]*)"Acer"([^{]*?},)/$1"TTTT"$2/gs'
```

I used perl v5.16.3 here which returns the following:

```
[
    {
        "manufacturer": "TTTT",
        "regularPrice": 165.99,
    },
    [
        "manufacturer": "Acer",
        "regularPrice": 165.99,
    ],
    {
        "manufacturer": "Acer",
        "regularPrice": 165.99,
    }
]
```

Note:

- -0777 slurp the entire file
- -p loop over lines and print them
- -e code in the command line
- substitution (s///) globally (g) and allow wildcards to match newline chars (s)